# Devise: Trying to setup a username field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise

I am trying to setup a username field with Devise using this tutoral: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

When logging in and everything, the login field works just fine, but when I try to reset my password, or resend a confirmation message I get an error with postgres:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column users.login does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "users".*      FROM "users" WHERE "users"."login" = 'nah... ^ : SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."login" = 'nahtnam' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Here is my application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :birthdate, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

Here is my users.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable,
         :authentication_keys => [:login]
  attr_accessor :login
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :firstname, :presence => true
  validates :lastname, :presence => true
  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
end
```

I think I setup the configs properly as well.

I have no clue whats wrong. I tried move the attr_accessor above the `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable` but that didnt really help.

The problem is that I got this working 100% on another application, its just not working for this! :(

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it!

I changed this part:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  else
    where(conditions).first
  end
end
```

to

```
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  if login = conditions.delete(:login)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
  else
    where(conditions).first
  end
end
```

Change `self.find_for_database_authentication` to `self.find_first_by_auth_conditions`

Comment: I tried your answer but same result I am also using active admin any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Buried at the [bottom of the wiki you linked](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#configure-devise-to-use-login-as-reset-password-or-confirmation-keys) it says that you need to add the following to your `config/initializers/devise.rb` file to "configure devise to use login as reset password or confirmation keys":

```
config.reset_password_keys = [ :login ]
config.confirmation_keys = [ :login ]
```

Also be sure to update your views as well. In `passwords/new.html.erb` remove:

```
<p><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %></p>
```

and add:

```
<p><%= f.label :login %><br />
<%= f.text_field :login %></p>
```

In `confirmations/new.html.erb`, remove:

```
<p><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></p>
```

and add:

```
<p><%= f.label :login %><br />
<%= f.text_field :login %></p>
```

Comment: I need to check, but did you restart `rails server`? Initializers only run when the rails server starts.

Comment: Nope, I restarted the server multiple times.

Comment: Hm. Does you have multiple models using devise? What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Nope, just one model (users). I am running 4.1.1.

Comment: That is quite weird. Could you try moving `reset_password_keys` and `confirmation_keys` into your `User` model—the same way you have `:authentication_keys => [:login]`?

Comment: Same problem. Do you want to continue you this on chat?

Comment: I would, but I think I'm all out ideas. I'd suggest [posting this as an issue the devise gem github page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/new). Your issue will go straight to the developers who work on devise, and who aren't necessarily on SO.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for helping out Joe! Ill make a github issue if no one can help me on irc.

Comment: No problem! Sorry I couldn't help you solve the issue. Hopefully somebody more knowledgable than me can help you solve it.

Comment: Hey! I finally fixed the issue! Check out my other answer.

Comment: Thanks alot :-) Fixed my issue